# Installing contextily on mac

Tags: python, contextily

I am trying to install contextily package and get the error below. Do you have any ideas how to overcome it? Cheers.

```
(base) 100KOTTONs-MacBook-Air:~ 100kotton$ pip3 install contextily
Collecting contextily
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/10/34/2aabf40c1acfb4b2f623e90f1a130eba80fd664a2d91c801558acebe3d3c/contextily-0.99.0.tar.gz
Collecting cartopy (from contextily)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e5/92/fe8838fa8158931906dfc4f16c5c1436b3dd2daf83592645b179581403ad/Cartopy-0.17.0.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /anaconda3/bin/python /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py get_requires_for_build_wheel /var/folders/h1/gt1kllm16qvd5s9ynxh21cy40000gn/T/tmphd534ujf
       cwd: /private/var/folders/h1/gt1kllm16qvd5s9ynxh21cy40000gn/T/pip-install-y8fj50xl/cartopy
  Complete output (3 lines):
  setup.py:171: UserWarning: Unable to determine GEOS version. Ensure you have 3.3.3 or later installed, or installation may fail.
    '.'.join(str(v) for v in GEOS_MIN_VERSION), ))
  Proj 4.9.0 must be installed.
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /anaconda3/bin/python /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py get_requires_for_build_wheel /var/folders/h1/gt1kllm16qvd5s9ynxh21cy40000gn/T/tmphd534ujf Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: have you tried updating `GEOS` first?